# Tag synonym for palaeontology

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Please consider adding paleontology as a tag synonym for palaeontology.

I think both are valuable to have, as in the long run, people from the states might go searching for the spelling without the 'a'.

I think this might have to be added in by an employee at this point, unless there's someone who has already reached the rep requirement and score within that tag to propose a synonym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we will need to create a fair few synonyms for English and American-English spellings as there are a fair few already that I am spelling differently to those in the US.  As well as the initial rep to suggest them is there not a requirement of questions answered within a tag for those who vote for the changes as well?  If that is the case we certainly could be a while away from sorting such things out without SE help.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant by answer score.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @jonsca  We're now at the stage where a couple of us have the necessary rep to at least propose the synonyms.  I'm thinking that it may be worth waiting to see how many people make the mistake first, however?  If we find ourselves continually re-tagging then perhaps that is the stage to make use of the feature.

Comment: Now that you're a freshly minted mod (congrats) you can do it directly! That's fine if you want to wait, I was always taught the American spelling, so I just assume most Americans spell it that way.